# Date format shows exception in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, date, cron

The shell script:

```
echo '/bin/date -d "1 days ago" +"%x"'
```

When I run the shell script directly from terminal the output is:

```
06/07/2013\n
```

But while I run script in the crontab, the output is:

```
06/07/13\n
```

I hope the output should be the same with the upper one.  If you know the reason, can you share with me.

Comment: Presumably, you used backquotes, not single quotes, when you ran this. The code above doesn't run `date`, but instead prints the literal command string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%x` flag means "locale's date representation". chrony has different locale settings compared to your user, to verify this try to execute the `locale` command under the cron user (ie adding `* * * * * root locale > /root/cron-locale` to /etc/crontab) ; you will see it is:

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

while running `locale` for your user account would probably return something like:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

To have a consistent date representation, use: `%Y` , which means 4-chars year